# DataTables not working within flask / jinja2 template

Tags: jquery, python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, datatables

I have a page where I would like to include some `DataTables`. Example code doesn't work if the `{% extends "navbar.html" %}` and `{% block content %}` are at the top of my document.

```
{% extends "navbar.html" %}
{% block content %}
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Sites</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>SitePoint</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Learnable</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Flippa</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $("#example").dataTable();
  })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

results in -->

**Sites**

SitePoint

Learnable

Flippa

Whereas removing the `{% extends navbar %}` and `{% block %}` imports gives me a working `DataTable`, albeit not styled at all. [See the tutorial here](http://www.sitepoint.com/working-jquery-datatables/). It's literally the code above exactly minus `navbar` and `block` as mentioned. I also tried removing the line `<link rel="stylesheet"....`

**EDIT**
Here is navbar.html

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% import "bootstrap/fixes.html" as fixes %}

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    {% if title %}
    <title>ERS - {{title}}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>BROKEN DESCRIPTORRR</title>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
           <!--<div>-->
           {% block navbar %}
      ...a bunch of stuff...

            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>

<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is some of `bootstrap.html`

```
<head>
    {%- block head %}
    ...stuff...
    {%- block styles %}
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{bootstrap_find_resource('css/bootstrap.css', cdn='bootstrap')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    {%- endblock styles %}
    {%- endblock head %}
  </head>
  <body{% block body_attribs %}{% endblock body_attribs %}>
    {% block body -%}
    {% block navbar %}
    {%- endblock navbar %}

    ...message stuff...

    {% block content -%}
    {%- endblock content %}

    {% block scripts %}
    <script src="{{bootstrap_find_resource('jquery.js', cdn='jquery')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{bootstrap_find_resource('js/bootstrap.js', cdn='bootstrap')}}"></script>
    {%- endblock scripts %}
    {%- endblock body %}
  </body>
```

Comment: You probably need to rethink your template inheritance. What does `navbar.html` look like?

Comment: @dirn Using the inspector in the browser, I see that I am calling stylesheets multiple times. Are there methods in flask to override these? `super()` doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: You are inserting everything in your template into the `content` block of `navbar.html`. You should only include the HTML you want in the block. In `navbar.html` you are including several script files outside of the HTML document. They should be inside it, ideally inside the `body` tag.

Comment: I'm also facing the exactly same issue. My code is neat and i don't have script tag in body. My Script tags are in head block of html.

Comment: I followed http://codepen.io/adobewordpress/pen/gbewLV and was able to create search field successfully. It was very easy.